# Spark Streaming read column with newline character in it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read a line passed from kafka through Spark streaming 
The incoming record has 4 columns and one of the column has newline characters with in it in double quotes

example

```
a ,b , "hi
how are you
fine
",d
```

So how to read or what options need to set while reading from kafka through spark streaming so record can be read correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending data correctly to kafka dstrean should look something like below when you stream records using spark.

a ,b , "hi how are you fine",d

Now you can split the record using the commas and map the values to a pojo class to create a dataframe/dataset having four columns